# type or namespace webjobs does not exist in the namespace azure

Tags: nuget-package, azure-webjobs

If I use nuget package Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs v 2.0.0 there is no problem. If I upgrade to 2.1.0 or 2.2.0 I get this compilation error.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What version with your webjobs, .net or .net core?And where you get this error, in local or on azure?

Comment: .net,  problem at local built VS 2017 (15.7.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I have tested, when your **.net framework version is <=4.6**, you upgrade to webjobs 2.2.0 it will get error.

Because when you upgrade from 2.0.0 to 2.2.0, it only add [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/),which dependence is .net standard 2.0.

If your .net framework version need to be match with the standard version.

So **make sure your .net framework greater or equal to .net framework 4.6**.

Comment: Thx. .net fw in project is 4.5.2. I'll upgrade it after next stable release.